# Fastest way to apply javascript to html for thousands of documents

Tags: javascript, c#, browser

Alot of pages don't contain their full html until the javascript has been applied, I need to webcrawl thousands of pages of said html in fully "rendered" form, but have no need for the visual aspect RAM wise or cpu wise to be taken up,

Case I'm using now, temporarily, WebBrowser control .Net,
CONS: rendering, full browser

Considering, selenium,
CONS: semi-full browser

Best option was phantomJS, which has been discontinued, is there a modern day equivalent that simply does:

```
string s = "<html><label id="lo"></label><script>document.getElementById('lo').innerHTML = 'dog';</script></html>
";

s = Magic.Parse(s)
//s is now "<html><label id="lo">dog</label><script>document.getElementById('lo').innerHTML = 'dog';</script></html>
";
```

Maybe it's a bad example, good example, on pages like google and bing they do this to slow down bot requests so people use their API

Any reccomendations and help appreciated.

Will be about 100 000 html files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer), It's a headless chrome similar to PhantomJS that google uses to crawl and parse websites for internal and public services.

If you need a library that can use with your C# code, your should check [CEFSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/) based in Chromium (open source Chrome) and updated with the last version.